# Удаление из списков определённых комбинаций

Tags: python

На входе имеются только координаты приёмников в той или иной конфигурации (например, крестообразная). Пусть координаты заданы следующим образом:

```
x = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3,  0, 0, 0]
```

Для того, чтобы выполнять последующие вычисления, необходимо найти следующие величины:

```
   b_x = x1 - x2
   b_y = y1 - y2
```

Для перебора всех возможных комбинаций вводится величина

```
antenna = np.arange(len(x))
```

И по ней осуществляется перебор всех возможных комбинаций координат:

```
    b_num = list(comb(antenna, 2))

b_x = []
for element in b_num:
    ant1 = element[0]
    ant2 = element[1]
    b_x.append(x[ant2] - x[ant1])

b_y = []
for element in b_num:
    ant1 = element[0]
    ant2 = element[1]
    b_y.append(y[ant2] - y[ant1])
```

Далее необходимо отсеить все разности b_x и b_y станций, которые находятся на одной линии (имеют одинаковый x или одинаковый y соответственно), и оставить только "**перекрёстные разности**". Как это сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для поиска разностей воспользуйтесь `numpy.diff` - это проще и быстрее. Я бы посоветовал получать не два разных списка, а один 2D-массив. Потому что потом из этой матрицы `x` легко получить нужные столбцы и строки: `x[:,3]`, например - четвертый столбец матрицы. Вам, как я понимаю, понадобится средний.